# Analyse data based on date

Tags: r, xts

I have a data frame spanning a couple of months, split into several values per day.  I have assigned one column as a date (using `as.Date()` ), but is it possible to run operations over data for a specific day?

For example, I want to run `summary()` on 29-04-14 and return only a summary for this particular date.

```
         Date     Time   col3   col4
6084 28-04-14 23:42:30   0.48 164.00
6085 28-04-14 23:47:00   0.39 150.00
6086 28-04-14 23:51:30   0.41 164.00
6087 28-04-14 23:56:00   0.33 160.00
6088 29-04-14 00:00:00   0.32 138.00
6089 29-04-14 00:04:30   0.15 141.00
6090 29-04-14 00:09:00   0.12 133.00
```

I have been trying for hours and  installed xts, but have had no success :(

Comment: Yes. It's possible. Provide a reproducible example showing where you're starting and where you want to end up, and I'm sure there will be several suggestions on how to get there.

Comment: It's impossible to tell by looking at this data what the data types of your columns are. Are they `Date`object? characters? factors? Do you want to run summary across all the columns? Only for one date or would you like to run `summary` for all dates?

Comment: @MrFlick - I'm assuming the dates are a `"Date"` object as I've assigned them using `as.Date()`.  The other values are a simple import via `read.csv()`.  I'm only using summary() as an example, ideally I want to run `median()`, `mean()`, `hist()` + others basic functions on both col3 and col4.  I just wanted to know if, considering I've defined Date as a date, if there was some nice and easy function that would spit out stats based on a specific date or date range.

Comment: When posting data in the future, please follow the recommendations of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possibility to get you started with the "xts" package.

Start with some sample data, as a `data.frame`:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Date = c("28-04-14", "28-04-14", "28-04-14", "28-04-14",
                                "29-04-14", "29-04-14", "29-04-14"), 
                       Time = c("23:42:30", "23:47:00", "23:51:30", "23:56:00", 
                                "00:00:00", "00:04:30", "00:09:00"), 
                       col3 = c(0.48, 0.39, 0.41, 0.33, 0.32, 0.15, 0.12), 
                       col4 = c(164, 150, 164, 160, 138, 141, 133)), 
                  .Names = c("Date", "Time", "col3", "col4"), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Convert it to an "xts" object:

```
library(xts)
myxts <- xts(mydf[-c(1, 2)], 
             as.POSIXct(paste(as.Date(mydf$Date, format="%d-%m-%y"), 
                              mydf$Time), tz=""))
```

It now looks like this:

```
myxts
#                     col3 col4
# 2014-04-28 23:42:30 0.48  164
# 2014-04-28 23:47:00 0.39  150
# 2014-04-28 23:51:30 0.41  164
# 2014-04-28 23:56:00 0.33  160
# 2014-04-29 00:00:00 0.32  138
# 2014-04-29 00:04:30 0.15  141
# 2014-04-29 00:09:00 0.12  133
```

The "xts" package has a lot of convenient time-based functions, like `apply.daily`, `apply.weekly`, and so on.

```
apply.daily(myxts, mean)
#                          col3     col4
# 2014-04-28 23:56:00 0.4025000 159.5000
# 2014-04-29 00:09:00 0.1966667 137.3333
```

It also lets you conveniently extract a specific date or time period:

```
myxts["2014-04-29"]
#                     col3 col4
# 2014-04-29 00:00:00 0.32  138
# 2014-04-29 00:04:30 0.15  141
# 2014-04-29 00:09:00 0.12  133
```

Here's what `summary` looks like for that particular date:

```
summary(myxts["2014-04-29"])
#      Index                          col3             col4      
#  Min.   :2014-04-29 00:00:00   Min.   :0.1200   Min.   :133.0  
#  1st Qu.:2014-04-29 00:02:15   1st Qu.:0.1350   1st Qu.:135.5  
#  Median :2014-04-29 00:04:30   Median :0.1500   Median :138.0  
#  Mean   :2014-04-29 00:04:30   Mean   :0.1967   Mean   :137.3  
#  3rd Qu.:2014-04-29 00:06:45   3rd Qu.:0.2350   3rd Qu.:139.5  
#  Max.   :2014-04-29 00:09:00   Max.   :0.3200   Max.   :141.0
```

Comment: this looks excellent, thanks... but it hasn't worked.  When I attempt: `myxts["29-04-14"]` only headers are returned.  When I attempt `apply.daily(myxts$col3, median)`, for some dates there is more than one entry: e.g.`27-04-14 00:22:41 0.605
28-04-14 00:22:30 0.500
28-04-14 23:56:00 0.435
29-04-14 00:22:30 0.160
29-04-14 23:57:32 0.460`

Comment: @ijf, an xts object is not a `data.frame`, so you con't access the columns the same way. Comments are not a good place to ask for clarification with code because the code is not reproduced properly. Either update your question or join the R Public chat room to try to get some clarification. Link back to this question and answer if you do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat your date like any other factor for the most part. If you want to run `summary` for each date, you can use the standard `by` function

```
by(data, data$Date, summary)
```

Date ranges are a bit more tricky. I might recommend using `cut.Date` or `seq.Date` to define data ranges and again using those as factors to collapse into groups you are interested in.